# Magento Store View: "Cannot add the item to shopping cart"

Tags: php, magento

I have a **Magento 1.7** shop with two store Views (one is for normal customers and the other one for VIPs with cheaper prices)

Without any change on the website, the VIP store view is showing this message when trying to add a product to the basket.

Cannot add the item to shopping cart.

I've checked the exception.log in the /var/ folder but it has nothing new written on it.

The other store view works fine.

How can I solve this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check the error if any in the console portion.

Comment: I've fixed it changing in FILE.php: 'cache_dir' => null, it was set to '/temp'; I don't know the working for this but now is working fine again...